# 'numpy' has no attribute 'dtype' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, attributeerror

I wonder if anyone know what happened to my program in python: as I tried a few different codes to se what would suit me and my task the best I ended up with the error `AttributeError: partially initialized module 'numpy' has no attribute 'dtype' (most likely due to a circular import)` (I wrote the entire error value at the bottom in case it would be of interest to anyone) and the program I am trying to run is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# x axis values
x = [1,2,3]

# corresponding y axis values
y = [2,4,1]

# plotting the points
plt.plot(x, y)

# naming the x axis
plt.xlabel('x - axis')
# naming the y axis
plt.ylabel('y - axis')

# function to show the plot
plt.show()
```

I have read on various pages to try to understand why this occurs but have not become much wiser, I have also renamed all my files in my python folder if any of these would be the problem but this still occurs and. It even occurs for different codes.

As I were trying to uninstall `matplotlib` with `pip uninstall matplotlib` I got:

```
Found existing installation: matplotlib 3.2.2
Uninstalling matplotlib-3.2.2:
  Would remove:
    /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib-3.2.2-py3.8-nspkg.pth
    /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib-3.2.2.dist-info/*
    /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/*
    /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/*
    /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid1/*
    /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/axisartist/*
    /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/*
    /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/tests/*
    /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pylab.py
Proceed (y/n)?
```

But then I can't answer yes or no for proceed, so its just frozen like that.

**Full error**: `

```
File "/Users/idalundmark/Desktop/Programmeringsteknik för matematiker (Labb)/Avklarade labbar/untitled6.py", line 10, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 139, in <module>
    from . import cbook, rcsetup

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    import numpy as np

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import core

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 83, in <module>
    from . import function_base

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/function_base.py", line 2, in <module>
    import scipy.interpolate

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/__init__.py", line 79, in <module>
    from numpy.random import rand, randn

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/random/__init__.py", line 181, in <module>
    from . import _pickle

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/random/_pickle.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .mtrand import RandomState

  File "mtrand.pyx", line 1, in init numpy.random.mtrand

AttributeError: partially initialized module 'numpy' has no attribute 'dtype' (most likely due to a circular import)`
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems like an issue with your library installation. Have you tried uninstalling and re-installing `matplotlib` ?

Comment: I tried that now, but it seem lika I cannot uninstall it. The kernel stops at `Proceed (y/n)? ` and I can't type in for neither yes or no.

Comment: "The kernel stops at Proceed (y/n)? and I can't type in for neither yes or no." Really? Did you try pressing either the `y` key or the `n` key, and then the `enter` key? Is there a blinking cursor? Is the terminal window active?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yes, I tried pressing both `y`and `n`. No, the terminal window is not active and the cursor for "Stop the current command" lights up red.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Of course I have clicked in the terminal but it does not help, the same problem remains and I still can't type in it. I used python and this program shortly before I wrote this post and everything worked fine then.

Comment: You can pass the `y` answer to conda directly by doing `conda install matplotlib -y`, for example

Comment: Thank you @FelipeWhitaker, but as an last option I uninstalled anaconda and reinstalled it again so it works now! But I will remember this if it ever happens again.